# How to stop the application when apache ignite is not started?

Tags: ignite

I have a sample spark application written in scala to push data to cache using apache ignite. As far as I know we have to start the ignite.sh in order to run the application. But if the ignite is not started the application hangs up forever. I tried changing the default ignite configuration, but of no use.

Is there a way to kill the application when ignite node is not started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join time out property need to be set to TCPDiscoverSPI, but we cannot use discovery api object set with configuration or config xml, as it will throw task not serializable exception. Below is the code that works perfectly for this situation, as it works in distributed mode and the SPI is not serializable class to share in distributed mode, which spark expects every function to be.

```
val ic = new IgniteContext[String, String](sc,() => {
      val cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
      val tc = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
      tc.setJoinTimeout(60000);
      cfg.setDiscoverySpi(tc);
      cfg})
```

This clears both the problems.

Comment: what kind of not serializable exception do you observe when using XML? In general, XML is just a Spring file which is used to construct an `IgniteConfiguration` object which is then used to create `IgniteContext`. So it should not make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

By default the client node will wait indefinitely for at least one server node to start. You can configure it to fail after a certain timeout if there are no servers:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="joinTimeout" value="60000"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I think, this will not work out with spark. It might work out with normal application. But, not withs spark. As, configuration and SPI will throw task not serializable exception. I found out the solution for this, and i am pasting the code below